# Is it "dyed blonde hair" or "dyed-blonde hair"?

Tags: adjectives, punctuation, compounds

What's the correct option? I find both instances on [Google Books](https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=%22her%20dyed%20blonde%20hair%22&tbm=bks&ei=ST0WWtepNMSu0ATqsKLgCA&start=20&sa=N&biw=1898&bih=950&dpr=1), so I'm a little confused.

Example sentence:

Mary had black cat-eye shades and **dyed blonde/dyed-blonde hair.**

Answer (score 1):

Though both might have been used, I may prefer writing it without any hyphen/dash. Because we **generally** use hyphens and dashes for the following writings:

> hyphens: when two things are intimately related. They go together: two-thirds 
>  *n* dash: to show distance: Sept-Dec (it also includes months in between) 
>  *m* dash: many uses; one of them is to have a break --as it's here.

How to do these dashes is [here](http://www.punctuationmatters.com/hyphen-dash-n-dash-and-m-dash/).
The reference for the answer is here: [CMOS](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/HyphensEnDashesEmDashes/faq0002.html)